# My Application Could not open ServletContext resource

Tags: web-applications, spring-mvc, spring-security, maven-eclipse-plugin

i have *Eclipse Maven* web project where i use *Spring mvc* and *Spring security*.
When i truy to launch it, it doesn't suceed to intialize the context:

`Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml]`

More details below:

---

This my `web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

<display-name>Web Manager</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
             /WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml, /WEB-INF/spring/security-config.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Spring MVC -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class> 
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

---

This my `app-config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

<!-- Scans the classpath of this application for @Components to deploy as beans -->
<context:component-scan base-package="fr.tessa.webmanager" />


<!-- Configures the @Controller programming model -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<!-- misc -->
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<!-- Configure the multipart resolver -->
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1000000" />
</bean>

<!-- Configures Hibernate - Database Config -->
<import resource="dbconfig/validationdb-config.xml" />
<import resource="dbconfig/db-config.xml" />
```

---

this is my `security-config.xml`

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome"
        authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
</http>
<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider>
    <user-service>
        <user name="mkyong" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
    </user-service>
  </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

---

my problem is when i launch the application i have error like

```
Infos: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml]
févr. 19, 2013 10:50:09 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
Grave: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:436)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1173)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:993)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4350)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4659)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded.start(Embedded.java:825)
at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractRunMojo.startContainer(AbstractRunMojo.java:558)
at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractRunMojo.execute(AbstractRunMojo.java:255)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml]
at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:140)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
... 48 more
```

It say that it not find `/WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml` but i did't put it in `web.xml`, my configuration file is `app-config.xml`

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Quote from the [Spring reference doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-servlet):

> Upon initialization of a DispatcherServlet, Spring MVC looks for a file named [servlet-name]-servlet.xml in the WEB-INF directory of your web application and creates the beans defined there...

Your servlet is called `spring-dispatcher`, so it looks for `/WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml`. You need to have this servlet configuration, and define web related beans in there (like controllers, view resolvers, etc). See the linked documentation for clarification on the relation of servlet contexts to the global application context (which is the `app-config.xml` in your case).

One more thing, if you don't like the naming convention of the servlet config xml, you can specify your config explicitly:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Comment: Thanks Zagyi, i removed "/WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml" from context-param and i outed in servlet init param and it work, +1 for your response :-)

Answer (score 8):

If you are getting this error with a Java configuration, it is usually because you forget to pass in the application context to the `DispatcherServlet` constructor:

```
AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
ctx.register(WebConfig.class);

ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = sc.addServlet("dispatcher", 
    new DispatcherServlet()); // <-- no constructor args!
dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
dispatcher.addMapping("/*");
```

Fix it by adding the context as the constructor arg:

```
AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
ctx.register(WebConfig.class);

ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = sc.addServlet("dispatcher", 
    new DispatcherServlet(ctx)); // <-- hooray! Spring doesn't look for XML files!
dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
dispatcher.addMapping("/*");
```

Comment: this was exactly my case

Comment: OMFG, 4 days and this helped. thanks. Just for the record.
Helps with wildfly 10 openshift deployment on standard spring boot app.
Also try to set in maven 
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your maven war plugin block in pom.xml includes all files (especially xml files) while building the war. But you don't need to include the .java files though.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>

  <configuration>
    <webResources>
      <resources>
        <directory>WebContent</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*.*</include> <!--this line includes the xml files into the war, which will be found when it is exploded in server during deployment -->
        </includes>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resources>
    </webResources>
    <webXml>WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this exception in WebLogic, turns out it is a bug in WebLogic. Please see here for more details: [Spring Boot exception: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34525967/spring-boot-exception-could-not-open-servletcontext-resource-web-inf-dispatch)

Answer (score -1):

```
The file name u used spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml
kindly check in web.xml
servlet name as spring-dispatcher at both tag  <servlet> and <servlet-mapping>
in your case it should be

<servlet>
<servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
<servlet-class></servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
<url-pattern></url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```