# Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Ok, I am 500th user asking this question, I read many [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14954931/my-application-could-not-open-servletcontext-resource) but still having no luck.

parent module pom contains:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Child module has `maven-jetty-plugin` and I run my webapp module with `jetty:run`.

`web.xml` defines standard dispatcher module:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I have file `dispatcher-servlet.xml` under `WEB-INF`, though start fails with:

```
FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
```

What is wrong? Documentation and everybody says that Spring MVC will search for XX-servlet.xml, where XX is name of servlet. Why does it search for `applicationContext.xml`?

Comment: Do you have a org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener registered as a <listener> element in your web.xml?

Comment: Right, well that is causing the issue then. By default the ContextLoaderListener will look for a Spring configuration at /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml. Simply remove the <listener> element and things should work fine.

Comment: @RobBlake Good catch! Copy it to answer so I can accept it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 72, accepted):

`ContextLoaderListener` has its own context which is shared by all servlets and filters. By default it will search `/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml`

You can customize this by using

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/somewhere-else/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

on `web.xml`, or remove this listener if you don't need one.

Comment: It is not shared but becomes the parent context or root context. Servlet contexts become children and thus can see beans in the parent but not the other way around. Which might have been what you meant.

Comment: This solved a completely different issue that has been plaguing me for the last day. Good on you.

Comment: What is "somewhere-else" supposed to be - sorry, im completely new to this?

Answer (score 25):

**Update:** This will create a second context same as in applicationContext.xml

or you can add this code snippet to your **web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
          <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

instead of

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Comment: Can you explain the difference? explanation?