# Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/application.xml]?

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

I see  many posts for this issue, but I'm still not clear how to resolve my issue.  I have a Maven app that is working fine with an external instance of Tomcat.  I was requested to switch this to an embedded instance of maven so I could run this with the `mvn tomcat7:run` command.

Fine, but now I get the exception listed below.  I don't know what setting is missing.  The error message is not helpful because it only lists a relative path: 
"Could not open ServletContext resource [**/WEB-INF/classes/application.xml**]".  There is a "**/WEB-INF/classes/application.xml**" file under my "target" folder that maven is building to, but apparently embedded tomcat is looking somewhere else, except I don't know where or how to tell it to look in "**/target/WEB-INF/classes/application.xml**"

How do I determine where the embedded tomcat instance is looking for this file ( the entire path, not just the relative path) and how do I update it?

Update -  I saw the link you referred me to.  It does not help.  I have a very specific question that is not addressed in the link you provided: How do I determine where the embedded tomcat instance is looking for this file?

> SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener
>   instance of class
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/classes/application.xml]; nested exception is
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/classes/application.xml]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
>         at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
>         at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:612)
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:513)
>         at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
>         at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
>         at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5291)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>       Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/application.xml]
>         at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:141)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)

Comment: Please provide detail how you are loading your spring application context. Usually you would do it in your web.xml. Copy paste that please and someone might help.

Comment: have you checked this [link](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/tomcat7-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html) , because it shows the property for both the classpath/webapps directory as well as the configurationDir

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not open ServletContext resource \[/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22350721/could-not-open-servletcontext-resource-web-inf-applicationcontext-xml)

Comment: None of this has helped.  How can I log the location where "/WEB-INF/classes/application.xml" is being searched for?

Comment: Look at the space where the path is given (applicationContext.xml) and try `classpath:/application.xml`.