# Error creating form in spring using spring form tag

Tags: spring, maven, jsp, spring-mvc

**Error 500**

JDK 1.8

Tomcat 8.0.38

HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /index1.jsp at line 11

type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /index1.jsp at line 11

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

```
    exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /index1.jsp at line 11

8: <title>Index 2</title>
9: </head>
10: <body>
11:     <form:form action="user_profile" method="post" commandName="abc">
12:         <form:label path="userID">Username</form:label>
13:         <form:input path="userID" />
14: 


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:579)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:471)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
    org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:90)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(RequestContextUtils.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.initContext(RequestContext.java:209)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.JspAwareRequestContext.initContext(JspAwareRequestContext.java:74)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.JspAwareRequestContext.<init>(JspAwareRequestContext.java:48)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:77)
    org.apache.jsp.index1_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(index1_jsp.java:179)
    org.apache.jsp.index1_jsp._jspService(index1_jsp.java:135)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

**index1.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Index 2</title>
</head>
<body>
<form:form action="user_profile" method="post" commandName="abc">
    <form:label path="userID">Username</form:label>
    <form:input path="userID" />


    <form:label path="firstName">First Name</form:label>
    <form:input path="firstName" />

    <form:label path="lastName">Last Name</form:label>
    <form:input path="lastName" />

    <form:label path="dateOfBirth">Date Of Birth</form:label>
    <form:input path="dateOfBirth" />


    <form:label path="gender">Gender</form:label>
    <form:input path="gender" />

    <form:label path="street">Street</form:label>
    <form:input path="street" />

    <form:label path="location">Location</form:label>
    <form:input path="location" />


    <form:label path="city">City</form:label>
    <form:input path="city" />

    <form:label path="state">State</form:label>
    <form:input path="state" />

    <form:label path="pincode">Pincode</form:label>
    <form:input path="pincode" />

    <form:label path="mobileNo">EmailID</form:label>
    <form:input path="mobileNo" />

    <form:label path="password">Password</form:label>
    <form:input path="password" />
    <input type="submit" value="clickMe">

</form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

**com.happiestminds.ocs.bean.ProfileBean.java**

```
package com.happiestminds.ocs.bean;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "OCS_TBL_USER_PROFILE")
public class ProfileBean {

    public ProfileBean(){

    }
    @Id
    @Column(name = "USERID")
    private String userID;

    @Column(name = "FIRSTNAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LASTNAME")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "DATEOFBIRTH")
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    @Column(name = "GENDER")
    private String gender;

    @Column(name = "STREET")
    private String street;

    @Column(name = "LOCATION")
    private String location;

    @Column(name = "CITY")
    private String city;

    @Column(name = "STATE")
    private String state;

    @Column(name = "PINCODE")
    private String pincode;

    @Column(name = "MOBILENO")
    private String mobileNo;

    @Column(name = "EMAILID")
    private String emailID;

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
    private String password;

    public String getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(String userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Date getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getPincode() {
        return pincode;
    }

    public void setPincode(String pincode) {
        this.pincode = pincode;
    }

    public String getMobileNo() {
        return mobileNo;
    }

    public void setMobileNo(String mobileNo) {
        this.mobileNo = mobileNo;
    }

    public String getEmailID() {
        return emailID;
    }

    public void setEmailID(String emailID) {
        this.emailID = emailID;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

**RegisterAndLoginController.java**

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.happiestminds.ocs.controller;

import java.util.Date;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.happiestminds.ocs.bean.ProfileBean;
import com.happiestminds.ocs.service.PatientService;

/**
 * @author Ankush
 *
 */
@Controller
public class RegisterAndLoginController {

    /*@Autowired
    private AdministratorService administratorService;*/

    @Autowired
    private PatientService patientService;

    /*@Autowired
    private ReporterService reporterService;*/

    //Autowiring ends here

    @RequestMapping(value = "user_profile",method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView registerUser(@ModelAttribute("abc") ProfileBean pf){

        System.out.println(pf.getUserID());
        System.out.println(pf.getFirstName());


        return new ModelAndView("test");
    }

}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>clinic</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/ocs/clinic-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>clinic</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index1.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

**WEB-INF/ocs/clinic-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:resources/database.properties" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.happiestminds.ocs" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager" />

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/clinicViews/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.happiestminds.ocs.bean.ProfileBean</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read your error logs

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?

You have to add in **web.xml**

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: if i add i get another error as                                                              **parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)**

Comment: review your code spring in searching for applicationContext.xml at incorrect path. 

try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22350721/could-not-open-servletcontext-resource-web-inf-applicationcontext-xml and be sure  that you indicated correct path to your configuration file.

Comment: i got it but i am setting my **ContextLoaderListener** in the param tag in **web.xml** then it should be ok and it should not ask me to include a listener tag according to the link you suggested me. Thanks but its not helping...

Comment: @GVArt's answer is the right one for me. The context config location you are setting in the dispatcher servlet applies only to it, you must use the ContextLoaderListener and it's configuration file.

Comment: Thanks it worked. i got confused between application context and servlet context.

Comment: For nothing, gl