# RestController in WebLogic Server Version: 12.2.1.0.0

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, weblogic12c, spring-restcontroller

I have deployed a RestController in WebLogic Server Version: 12.2.1.0.0.

Here the notation of the method

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/hotelAssessment/saveHotelAssessment")
    @ResponseBody
    public CommonResponse<Void> saveHotelAssessment(@RequestBody PersistHotelAssessmentRequest persistHotelAssessmentRequest) {
..
}
```

In the Json object I have 1 property named  "creationDate"
if I send  `"creationDate": null` everything is OK, but if I send  `"creationDate": "11/03/2019"`

I got this error calling the WS

```
]] Root cause of ServletException.
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:343)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:194)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml]
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:159)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:329)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:223)
```

Comment: Are you using any xml definition?

Comment: no, I am not using any XML  definition

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34525967/spring-boot-exception-could-not-open-servletcontext-resource-web-inf-dispatch

Comment: It seems to be a problem with Oracle Weblogic. In that discussion you can also find a workaround for getting it work.